# One-dimensional deblurring

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

I just begun studying image deblurring on my own, and I have a question.
Most books I found say that I can see the images as arrays, and that I can "vectorize" the arrays of the images by stacking the columns.
So, the image is reresented by a vector, and I have a linear system (something like $g = K * f$, where $g$ is the blurred image and $f$ the original one).

Then when developing the subject and introducing the convolution and the boundary conditions, why should I use a 2D convolution? Why should I treat the image as a matrix (better, an array), if I can use it as a vector?
Or do I just use the 2D convolution for color images and 1D for b&w?

I am a little confused...I hope the question is clear, though.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The kernel K has certain properties like e.g. being invariant under translations.

Comment: What does this mean? It implies that I should use the $2D$ instead of $1D$? Why?